# Dynamic function to calculate polyserial correlation

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
lm
TouchPoints   Gross_LM   Gross_rev     Score        Local_Rev_LM
    Y           57.41      96.96       0.87             0.36
    N           59.87      40.6        0.51             3.38
    Y          129.94      228.7       0.8              20.68
    N          148.58      205.4       0.65             26.8
    Y           161.1      179.95      0.04             23.34
```

I am using simple code for getting correlaion between two variables i.e.  TouchPoints & Gross_LM:

```
library(polycor)
polyserial(lm$Gross_LM, lm$TouchPoints)
[1] 0.006737169
```

Now, I want to calculate polyserial correlation between a fixed categorical value i.e. (TouchPoints) with rest all the other variables i.e. Gross_LM, Gross_rev etc.

In other words, I want to have dynamic function which will calculate polyserial correlation for "n" number of rows.

The dynamic function should save the output in following manner:

```
nm
Variables       Polyserial Correlation with TouchPoints
Gross_LM          0.006737169
Gross_rev         0.00396954
Score             0.1178589
Local_Rev_LM     -0.2872475
```

Thanks in advance for providing the solution!!

Comment: You could just loop through the variables, `sapply(names(d)[-1], function(x) polyserial(d[,x], d$TouchPoints) )`, or depending on how big your data is you could do this using `hetcor`, which takes data.frames (inefficient to calculate all the extra correlations but easy to use (`hetcor(d, std.err = FALSE, ML=FALSE, pd=FALSE)`)